# Send A File In C Sharp with UDP Protocol From A Computer To Other Computer

Tags: c#, .net, networking, udp, .net-3.5

I Want Send A File From A Computer To Other Computer With UDP protocol.How Can I do this?

I Want A Sample To Send File...

Comment: Use the Random class, it's behavior is more predictable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [UdpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx).

Delivery is not guaranteed with UDP - if you have to break the file up, this is especially problematic.  See here for a discussion - [How to send large data using C# UdpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319521/how-to-send-large-data-using-c-udpclient)

If this is point-to-point (as the question suggests), it would be simple to write some native code to do this using [TransmitFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740565(VS.85).aspx).

> The TransmitFile function transmits
>   file data over a connected socket
>   handle. This function uses the
>   operating system's cache manager to
>   retrieve the file data, and provides
>   high-performance file data transfer
>   over sockets.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [UdpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx) Class.

Answer (score 2):

UDP has no inherent knowledge of files (it is much lower in the protocol stack), so it might be worth investigating one of the established [UDP-based file transfer protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_transfer_protocols#Primarily_used_with_UDP).  Some of them might have .NET implementations.

Otherwise, you are going to be doing a lot of work on your own (e.g. ensuring that the file is broken up into pieces, making sure that all packets are received AND that they are received in the correct order, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The link below shows various examples of how to send and receive UDP packets with C#

http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/UdpClientMultiReceive.htm